# Verifying the existence of a file in the terminal

Tags: git, terminal, git-clone, nosuchfileexception

I am copying some code from GitHub, but when I try accessing a file within, the terminal outputs "No such file or directory".

I've tried looking for the files manually on the computer but indeed I cannot find them.

My guess is that the cloning is saving the codes somewhere else, and when I try to change to the directory it cannot access it since it does not exist in the computer.

Here is what I get to see in the terminal:

```
fun4all@Fun4AllSingularity:~$ git clone https://github.com/sPHENIX-Collaboration/macros.git
Cloning into 'macros'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8930, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (422/422), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (179/179), done.
remote: Total 8930 (delta 278), reused 348 (delta 241), pack-reused 8508
Receiving objects: 100% (8930/8930), 1.84 MiB | 1.72 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5193/5193), done.
fun4all@Fun4AllSingularity:~$ cd macros/macros/g4simulations/
bash: cd: macros/macros/g4simulations/: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure if it is important, but I am using a virtual box, this is not on my local computer.

Also, it worked before, just recently it started giving this problem.

Comment: When I look at https://github.com/sPHENIX-Collaboration/macros there is no `macros/g4simulations` folder either.

Comment: Once try checking the directory tree using following command once and then try cd 
"ls * -r"

Comment: But there used to be.  The mdc-3 tag has them, mdc-4 tag (and later) do not. I don't know what I'm looking at there so you'd have to ask them why they got removed.

Answer (score 2):

The `g4simulation` directory no longer exists in this repository. It was removed back in January in [commit 0c6692376c9920588290121ed0174ddeda102e22](https://github.com/sPHENIX-Collaboration/macros/commit/0c6692376c9920588290121ed0174ddeda102e22).

Presumably it is no longer needed since the title of the commit is:

> ditch obsolete g4simulation directory

Answer (score 0):

Based on **https://github.com/sPHENIX-Collaboration/macros** this folder does not exist in the current `master` branch anymore.

As Mureinik pointed out, it was removed a while ago.

However, the folder still exists in the stale branch `readback_check`.

So if you still want to go to that directory - for whatever reason, you'll have to checkout that particular branch first.

```
cd macros
git checkout readback_check
cd macros/g4simulations/
```